# Google Pay API: Braintree Gateway Configurations

Tags: paypal, braintree, google-pay

I'm just getting started with Google Pay API and I planned to use Braintree as the gateway. According to the [Google Pay API Doc here](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial#apiversion), we have to specify the `sdkversion` number of `braintree.client.VERSION`:

```
  "gateway": "braintree"
  "braintree:apiVersion": "v1"
  "braintree:sdkVersion": "braintree.client.VERSION"
  "braintree:merchantId": "YOUR_BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID"
  "braintree:clientKey": "YOUR_BRAINTREE_TOKENIZATION_KEY"
```

**My questions:**

1. Where can we find the **version number** of `braintree.client` and what would be the syntax to specify the version number? According to the [Braintree's doc here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/google-pay/client-side/javascript/v3), there are so many version numbers and seems like `3.40.0` is the latest. Shall we put `braintree.client.3.40.0`?
2. What is `braintree:apiVersion` on the other hand?
3. Is it possible to use my PayPal merchant ID since I've generated my **Braintree SDK Credential** from within my PayPal's **API Access** setting?
4. For `braintree.clientKey`, it should be the **Braintree SDK Credential** that I've generated with PayPal, am I right?

It's kind of confusing, hope someone can shed me some light, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, signup for the Braintree Sandbox:

https://www.braintreepayments.com/sandbox

Configure Google Pay on the Braintree Sandbox account,

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/google-pay/configuration/javascript/v3

Get the JavaScript SDK
[See the client SDK setup guide for JavaScript v3.](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/setup/javascript/v3)

Use Drop-In type of integration which is easy one.

Then, go onto Server Side integration,

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/google-pay/server-side/node

**To obtain a tokenization key, follow these steps:**

1. Log into either the sandbox Control Panel, depending on which environment you are working in
2. Click on the gear icon in the top right corner
3. Click API from the drop-down menu
4. Scroll to the Tokenization Keys section
5. If no key appears, click the Generate New Tokenization Key button.

**To find your merchant ID:**

1. Log into the sandbox Control Panel, depending on which environment you are working in
2. Click on the gear icon in the top right corner
3. Click Business from the drop-down menu
4. You'll find your merchant ID at the top of this page.

Your merchant ID can also be found when logged into your Control Panel, as the string of letters and numbers following /merchants/ in the URL.

Note: You cannot use PayPal Merchant Id here in the Braintree integration.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but first, my question is on **Google Pay API** implementation that requires the `VERSION` number of Braintree client library; second, I already have the Braintree sandbox account, but I'm more curious about the production merchant ID because I can't even sign-up for the Braintree production as it keeps leading me to sandbox account. I do not want to end up having no production merchant ID to go live.

Comment: Client version: Braintree supports Google Pay since version V3.29.0. googlePayVersion: 2,  apiVersion: 2. You should contact sales to get a production account. Goto home page of Braintree https://www.braintreepayments.com/ and hit contact sales button.